# Correct method to fix html so it is ready for a mysql query?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I forgot what was needed in PHP
in PHP i think all you'd have to do was..

```
$html_code = addslashes($html_code);
```

in Python is there a "addslashes" equivalence so i can try it out ?

Comment: What do you mean, you want to insert HTML into a database and avoid SQL injection and / or escaping problems?

Comment: yes i would like to add html into mysql database, i am not worried about sql injection at this time

Comment: FYI, using `addslashes` in PHP is **ALWAYS WRONG** and **NOT SUFFICIENT**.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the escaping to the database API, and use SQL parameters:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (%s)', (html_value,))
```

By using a SQL parameter (here using the MySQLdb parameter style `%s`) and passing in the value as a separate argument, the database API escapes the value for you as appropriate, preventing SQL injection as a bonus.

HTML is no different from other string values in this respect.